# Cartesian product of integers and integers equals integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Does: $\mathbb{Z} \mathsf{X} \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$  ? or $\mathbb{Z}^*  (= \mathbb{N}$)  ?

Comment: When you write "=", what do you mean? The question has different answers for different senses of equality.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of pairs, whereas $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of numbers. They cannot be equal.

Comment: I don't recognize the notation; it's better to just say what you mean than try to make up some ascii approximation. Just in case they're helpful, `\times \subset \subseteq \leq \star` in mathmode give $\times \subset \subseteq \leq \star$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the basic level of the question we need a basic level in answer. The are not equal. In set theory two object (i.e. sets) are equal precisely if they are indistinguishable. $x$ and $y$ are equal if for every formula $F(x)\equiv F(y)$. Id est if doesn't exist any "sentence" which can see $x$ and $y$ as different objects.
Given that you have that $0=\emptyset\in\mathbb{Z}$ but $0\notin\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, so the two sets are different.
However in some contexts they could be seen as equivalent by a certain family of functions if interested in particular properties. For example, the are equal in cardinality as there exists a bijection $\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$